# vapply vs for loop speed/efficiency in R -- vapply significantly worse?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

I long thought that the `*apply` family of functions where preferred in R over vanilla `for` loops since they are supposedly faster and have no side effects.  I decided to test this with a trivial example using `microbenchmark` and was shocked that `vapply` is actually SIGNIFICANTLY slower.

I have seen posts on SO saying that they are basically the same, but none where `for` loops significantly outperform an `apply` statement. This made me wonder if perhaps I should be writing `for` loops instead in some instances.

```
bob = function()
{
  x=vector(mode='numeric',length=100)
  for(i in 1:100)
  {
    x[i]=i+i
  }
  x
}



> microbenchmark(bob(),unit='ns')
Unit: nanoseconds
  expr  min     lq    mean median     uq   max neval
 bob() 5306 5399.5 5606.32 5486.5 5584.5 15123   100

   > microbenchmark(vapply(1:100,function(x) x+x,FUN.VALUE = numeric(1)),unit='ns')
Unit: nanoseconds
  expr   min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
 [...] 46781 48370.5 61478.68  49319 51696.5 1029655   100

#lapply isn't any better
> microbenchmark(lapply(1:100,function(x) x+x),unit='ns')
Unit: nanoseconds
  expr   min    lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 [...] 43931 45919 62958.69 46736.5 47674.5 1616723   100
```

Comment: You aren't actually benchmarking your function here - change the call to bob(), and you can see times are more comparable (still 10* slower though). You are also mistaken that for loops are necessarily slow - when pre allocating like you have done here, they are pretty fast. Compare to `microbenchmark(1:100 + 1:100)`

Comment: Ah, thanks!! I knew there was no way they where that different.  Post updated with proper call.

Comment: Also try running the bob() function without preallocating the space for x.  `x=vector()` Now the difference is closer to 2x.

Comment: @Dave2e I was under the impression that vapply prealocated memory based on the input and expected output which is why I preallocated x to keep the comparison even